# How to delete the middle element of a stack in O(1) time complexity?

Tags: data-structures, stack, time-complexity

Well, I tried this question on GeeksforGeeks using an array. But the solution in GeeksforGeeks says that we have to use linked list for deleting the middle element of a stack in O(1) time complexity. But I have a solution for this using array also, which I want to confirm that is it correct or not. The solution to delete the middle element is: -

Suppose we have a stack named stk[]

1. Find the middle element by computing m=(Top+1)/2
2. Swap the values of stk[Top] and stk[m]
3. Remove the top-most element
4. Then again swap the values stk[Top] and stk[m]

And in case when the no of stack elements are less than 3, just delete the top-most element from the stack.
I think this solution also has a time complexity of O(1) as there are no loops running here. So can anyone tell that is it a correct solution for this problem or not ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to [this puzzle](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-middle-element-stack/). Your approach changes the order of elements. For example, if the stack is

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

(with 1 at the bottom and 7 at the top), then after step 2 we have

`1 2 3 7 5 6 4`

and after step 3

`1 2 3 7 5 6`

and finally after step 4

`1 2 3 6 5 7`

, which is not what we wanted (we wanted `1 2 3 5 6 7`).

Furthermore, your approach breaks the abstraction proposed by the puzzle, which is to only use the stack operations `push()`, `pop()` and `empty()`. You shouldn't access the underlying array directly. Then again, the puzzle breaks its own abstraction when it uses recursion. Recursion has its own stack, which is effectively an additional data structure.